# Laravel. Различие между "file" и "cookie" сессионным драйвером

Tags: laravel, сессия, auth

Доброго времени суток!

Документация:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#driver-prerequisites

- file - sessions are stored in storage/framework/sessions.
- cookie - sessions are stored in secure, encrypted cookies.

Как понимает мой мозг:

**file** - хранит данные сессии в куках (факт) и зашифрованные сессионные файлы в storage/framework/sessions (факт).

Они формируются при любом запросе, так как входят в фильтр web. При следующем запросе данные с куки шифруются и сравниваются с тем, что в файле.

Этим laravel понимает, что данные отправляет один и тот же пользователь.

После laravel сохраняет новые данные в файле и отправляет, опять же, новые куки для пользователя.

**cookie** - по факту увидел, что данные хранятся только в куки. Но как и с чем сравниваются данные для определения пользователя - неясно.

Пожалуйста, внесите ясность.

Comment: Нет, вы все неправильно понимаете. Ничего ни с чем не сравнивается ни в том, ни в другом случае.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, можете рассказать поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот смотрите, вы пишите - *"Этим laravel понимает, что данные отправляет один и тот же пользователь."*. А откуда laravel вообще знает какой пользователь отправляет данные? Что, пользователь работает с ним всего 1?